# what is the canon 18-55mm IS lens good for?

Tags: lens, canon

is the canon 18-15mm lens good for self portraits and nature pictures {trees, leaves, DETAILED rain or snow} ?

Answer (score 0):

An 18-55mm lens is a wide angle to wider side of standard zoom lens.  It's a little wide for most portrait work, though it could do full body portraits alright on an APS-c camera (which you most likely have given the lens model that was included).  It should be able to do any wide angle landscape work alright, but will be limited when it comes to zooming in on any scenery that is in the distance.

As for self-portraits, your best bet there is a lens that is good for normal portraits and then using a tripod and remote trigger or timer.

Also, for photos of rain or snow, you need to take care to protect the camera from the elements.  If both your camera and your lens aren't weather sealed, then exposure to moisture or excessive dust isn't good for the camera.